# Regex Problem (newbie)

Tags: regex, url

i'm writing a little app for spam-checking and i'm having problems with a regex.

let's say i'm having this spam-url:

```
http://hosting.tyumen.ru/tip.html
```

so i want to check its url for having 2 full stops (subdomain+ending), a slash, a word, full stop and "html".

here's what i got so far:

```
<a href="(http://.*?\..*?..*?/.*?.html)">(http://.*?\..*?..*?/.*?.html)</a>
```

might look like rubbish but it works - the problem: it's really slow and freezing my app.

any hints on how to optimize it?
thx.re

Comment: If you're complaining about performance and crashing, it would be very useful to have platform information

Comment: The many vague `.*` are the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(http://[\w.-]+/.+?\.html)` - may be will work for your case only.

or may be faster one

```
(http://[\w.-]+/[^.]+\.html)
```

Comment: This matches almost any valid URL ending in ".html" and is slow for long documents with URLs not ending in ".html". I don't think this answers the question at all. I don't understand why it has been accepted as the best answer?

Comment: Update: the second version is a little faster, but it still matches far more than was asked for and it is still will be slow for URLS without an extension (this is quite common in the real world - see stackoverflow for example).

Comment: As I have mentioned, it will work only for his case only.
Do you really think `http://[^"]+\.[^"]+\.[^"]+/[^"]+.html` is faster than `http://[\w\d.-]+/[^.]+\.html`? I really dont think so.

Comment: I am just improving his regex, ok? of coz it will not match on stackoverflow, his original regex hardcoded as only .html already

Comment: Your regular expression can still be slow in many real world situations, it matches far more than what he asked for (almost every valid URL ending HTML) and it can even match two seperate links like this: <a href="http://localhost/">This one is safe</a> but this is spam: <a href="http://foo.bar.com/baz.html">http://foo.bar.com/baz.html</a>. Your regex will capture both links and the intervening text in one match.

Comment: That comment got mangled. There is not room to discuss it here, sorry.

Comment: for that case, I will suggest him to use html parser.

Comment: >> can still be slow in many real world situations,
please show me faster one then. I will be interested to benchmark it.

Comment: `<a href=http://google.com>http://google.com</a>` possible actually, `[^"]+` will even match `.html`, because its greedy match.

Answer (score 5):

The reason it's slow is that the non-greedy operators `?` being used this way is prone to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Instead of saying "any amount of anything, but only to an extent where it doesn't conflict with later requirements", which is effectively what `.*?` is saying, try asking for "as much as possible, that isn't a double quote, which would terminate the `href` ":

```
<a href="(http://[^"]+\.[^"]+\.[^"]+/[^"]+.html)">\1</a>
```

I also added a back-reference (`\1`) to your first capturing group, inside the `<a>...</a>`, so that you don't have to do the exact same matching all over again.

Note that this regex will be broken if, say, the `a` has a class name, an id, or anything else in its body. I left it like this because I wanted to give you what you asked for with as few changes as possible, and as to-the-point as possible.

Comment: For your subdomain and domain name matching (atleast), I'd be using `[^".]+` to help even more with backtracking.

Comment: It doesn't quite work though: it has false matches such as http://localhost/doc_v1.0.0.html. You could use [^/"] instead.

Comment: +1 that's a great point, altho omitting the escape would be quite fatal to that ;) `[^"\.]+`

Comment: @Mark: my prev response was to Matthew, altho +1 for you too; that's a different aspect of pretty much the same error. so to sum it all up: `[^/\."]+`

Comment: +1 for bringing formal content to the question, not just the solution

Comment: just a note: inside [] dot . has no special meaning. [.]+ will not match everything, but only dots.

Comment: ah. that was news to me. so my remark to matthew was quite uncalled for then. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2):

Since you claim to be a regexp newbie, I will offer a more general advice on creating and debugging regular expressions. When they get pretty complicated, I find using [Regexp Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) a must.

It's a freeware and really saves a lot of headache. Not to mention you don't have to build / run your application every minute just to see if the regexp works the way you wanted.

Comment: Or, if you're using Emacs, re-builder

Comment: Another good one is RegexBuddy, though not freeware (but not expensive either by any stretch).

Answer (score 0):

```
#http://[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[-a-zA-Z]+/\w+\.html#
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, a simple way to match URLs ending in .html or .htm is to use

```
url_re = re.compile(
    r'https?://' # http:// or https://
    r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|' #domain...
    r'localhost|' #localhost...
    r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' # ...or ip
    r'(?::\d+)?' # optional port
    r'(?:\S+.html?)+' # ending in .html
     , re.IGNORECASE)
```

which is a modified version of Django's UrlField regex.

This will match any site ending with .html or .htm. (either localhost, ip, domain).